# If the limit of a sequence of continous functions is upper semicontinous, is there a decreasing subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis

Hi everyone: Let $ V $ be an open set in $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $, $ n\geq2 $. We know that if  $ (f_{n}) $ is a decreasing sequence of continuous functions that converges to some function $ f $ on $V$, then $ f $ is upper semi-continuous. How about the converse of this theorem in the following sense: Let $ (f_{n}) $  a sequence of continuous (or even $ C- $infinity)functions that converges to some function $ f $. If $ f $ is upper semi-continuous, can we conclude that there exists a subsequence 
 $ f_{n_{k}} $   that decreases to $ f $, as $ k $ approaches infinity?